# "Invalid File Format" error when trying to submit form

Tags: php

When I try to submit my form, it can't be submitted and shows an "invalid file format" error, no matter if any data is input or not. The file format code was collected from StackOverflow.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $type=2;
    $fname = @$_POST['f_name'];
    $eml = @$_POST['email_id'];
    $mo_num = @$_POST['mn'];
    $message = @$_POST['message'];
    $uploaded_file_a= @$_FILES['file_a']['name'];
    $uploaded_file_b= @$_FILES['file']['name'];


// in a Array > all Supported Document Formats are Stored //
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "ppt", "pptx","jpeg","jpg","png","x-png");

// In a Temporary Array > The File Name + File Extension is Stored //
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

// Getting the Extension //
$extension = end($temp);
// Checking File // PDF | DOC | DOCX | XLS | XLSX | PPT | PPTX
if ((
   (@$_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpeg")
|| (@$_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpg") 
|| (@$_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/png") 
|| (@$_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/x-png")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"))
&& 
(@$_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

{
    $fileName_a = date("YmdHis") . "_" . $_FILES['file_a']['name'];
    $fileName = date("YmdHis") . "_" . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $valToBind = array(

                        ':F_NM' => $fname,                  
                        ':EM' => $eml,
                        ':MOB' => $mo_num,
                        ':TY' => $type,
                        ':MS' => $message,
                        ':PILEA'=> @$fileName_a,
                        ':PILE'=> @$fileName
                    );
$query = $conn1->prepare("
INSERT INTO `testimonials` (`user_name`,`email`,`phone`,`testimonial_type`,`testimonial_message`,`photo_file`,`image_file`) VALUES
(:F_NM,:EM,:MOB,:TY,:MS,:PILEA,:PILE);
    ");
            $query->execute($valToBind);    
            $rowNumber = $query->rowCount();
            $lastInsertId = $conn1->lastInsertId();
            if($lastInsertId > 0)
                            {
                                {   move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['file_a']['tmp_name'], "admin/upload/testimonials/". $fileName_a
                                );}
        {   move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "admin/upload/testimonials/". $fileName
                                );}
                                echo '<div class="alert alert-success " >
                            Your Testimonials has been sent to us.
                        </div>';

                        }
}   
else
{
    echo'<div class="alert alert-success " > Invalid File Format </div>';
}

        }
        ?>  

<form class="row contact_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_name" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">                        
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email_id" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mn" placeholder="Mobile Number">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
    <label> Your Photo</label><br>
         <input type="file" name="file_a" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
    <label> Testimonial in msword, pdf or Image (if scanned)</label><br>
         <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
         <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Testimonial Message (if written)"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Resume" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please format the question properly

Comment: Put your errors in a code block as well please.

Comment: your query is wrong, echo your query and try to run in phpmyadmin

Comment: your file submission code is working fine, the case which you need to handle is if the file is not selected and still you submit the form they it will give invalid file.

Answer (score 0):

i have modified you code to handle if no file is submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $type=2;
    $fname = @$_POST['f_name'];
    $eml = @$_POST['email_id'];
    $mo_num = @$_POST['mn'];
    $message = @$_POST['message'];
    $uploaded_file_a= @$_FILES['file_a']['name'];
    $uploaded_file_b= @$_FILES['file']['name'];


// in a Array > all Supported Document Formats are Stored //
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "ppt", "pptx","jpeg","jpg","png","x-png");

// In a Temporary Array > The File Name + File Extension is Stored //
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

// Getting the Extension //
$extension = end($temp);
// Checking File // PDF | DOC | DOCX | XLS | XLSX | PPT | PPTX
if ((
   (@$_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpeg")
|| (@$_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpg") 
|| (@$_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/png") 
|| (@$_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/x-png")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
|| (@$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"))
&& 
(@$_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts) && $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] != '')

{
    $fileName_a = date("YmdHis") . "_" . $_FILES['file_a']['name'];
    $fileName = date("YmdHis") . "_" . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $valToBind = array(

                        ':F_NM' => $fname,                  
                        ':EM' => $eml,
                        ':MOB' => $mo_num,
                        ':TY' => $type,
                        ':MS' => $message,
                        ':PILEA'=> @$fileName_a,
                        ':PILE'=> @$fileName
                    );
$query = $conn1->prepare("
INSERT INTO `testimonials` (`user_name`,`email`,`phone`,`testimonial_type`,`testimonial_message`,`photo_file`,`image_file`) VALUES
(:F_NM,:EM,:MOB,:TY,:MS,:PILEA,:PILE);
    ");
            $query->execute($valToBind);    
            $rowNumber = $query->rowCount();
            $lastInsertId = $conn1->lastInsertId();
            if($lastInsertId > 0)
                            {
                                {   move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['file_a']['tmp_name'], "admin/upload/testimonials/". $fileName_a
                                );}
        {   move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "admin/upload/testimonials/". $fileName
                                );}
                                echo '<div class="alert alert-success " >
                            Your Testimonials has been sent to us.
                        </div>';

                        }
}   
else
{
    echo'<div class="alert alert-success " > Invalid File Format </div>';
}

        }
        ?>  

<form class="row contact_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_name" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">                        
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email_id" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mn" placeholder="Mobile Number">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
    <label> Your Photo</label><br>
         <input type="file" name="file_a" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
    <label> Testimonial in msword, pdf or Image (if scanned)</label><br>
         <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
         <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Testimonial Message (if written)"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Resume" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks
Amit